# Unable to make HTTP Delete request in my ruby code using Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby, http, rest

Im using Net::HTTP in my ruby code to make http requests. For example to make a post request i do

```
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.post_form(url,{'email' => email,'password' => password})
```

This works. But im unable to make a delete request, i.e.

```
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP::Delete(url)
```

gives the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `Delete' for Net::HTTP:Class
```

The documentation at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html shows Delete is available. So why is it not working in my case ?

Thank You

Answer (score 6):

The documentation tells you that Net::HTTP::Delete is a class, not a method.

Try `Net::HTTP.new('www.server.com').delete('/path')` instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
uri = URI('http://localhost:8080/customer/johndoe')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
req = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri.path)
res = http.request(req)
puts "deleted #{res}"
```

Comment: if params needed to be sent along : `req.body = "name=test&num=1"`

Answer (score 1):

Simple post and delete requests, see [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) for more:

```
puts Net::HTTP.new("httpbin.org").post("/post", "a=1").body
puts Net::HTTP.new("httpbin.org").delete("/delete").body
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
uri = URI(YOUR_URL)
req = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri, {}) # params on second place
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
  http.request req
end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).