# How to fire Delete method in HTTP request using Net::HTTP class in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httprequest, google-calendar-api, http-delete

I am working with google calendar in rails app. I have fetch all the events and now I want to delete the event from rails app. for that I get `calendar.events.delete` method from google calendar api. But I am not aware hot to fire `delete` request in http. I have tried [all these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821197/unable-to-make-http-delete-request-in-my-ruby-code-using-nethttp)
 From [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.delete?calendarId=my_calendar_id%2540gmail.com&eventId=mycalendar%27seventID&_h=2&) I could successfully delete the specific event from my google calendar.

When I execute in google apis explorer by providing required details I got this url for delete the event:

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{MY_CALENDAR_ID}%40gmail.com/events/mycalendar'seventID?key={MY_API_KEY}
```

For this I tried:

```
url = URI(url_path)
request = Net::HTTP.new(url)
request.delete
```

and

```
  uri = URI.parse(url_path)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri.request_uri) 
  http.request(request)
 => #Error : end of file reached
```

I had also look this class library: [Net::HTTP::Delete](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP/Delete.html)  but here `Delete` is a class not method.

This way I am getting calendar's all events:

```
    source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar_ido%40gmail.com/events?key={MY_KEY}'
    gcalendar_resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(source))
    data = gcalendar_resp.body
    result = JSON.parse(data)
```

Can any one help me How can I fire delete request?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Net::HTTP.new('www.server.com').delete('/path')
```

Or:

```
uri = URI('url')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
req = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri.path)
res = http.request(req)
puts "deleted #{res}"
```

Comment: This is alreay I tried from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821197/unable-to-make-http-delete-request-in-my-ruby-code-using-nethttp